# Rails: Change _destroy functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for some nested resources and am using the `_destroy` flag to remove an item on form save.

But instead of `_destroy` actually running `DELETE` on a record, I'd like it to just update an `active` boolean field to be false.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehm.. So why do you use `_destroy`? Just add `active` checkbox istead of `_destroy`

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for @some_nested_object do |b| %>
    ...
    <%= b.check_box :active %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```